# Return frequency of words in a column along with Row it is associated with

Tags: python, string, nlp, analytics, frequency

I have a dataset with a text column containing sentences and an ID column. I was able to count the frequency of how many times each word is repeated in the text column using `data.text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()`.
But my goal is to pull out word frequency, along with the id column to which this word is associated with.

INPUT :

| Text | ID |
| --- | --- |
| He best work move happy | 1 |
| unemployed bad season | 1 |
| best way margin | 2 |
| frustated unemployed | 3 |

Desired OUTPUT :

| Word | frequency | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| best | 2 | 1 |
| best | 2 | 2 |
| frustrated | 1 | 1 |
| unemployed | 2 | 1 |
| unemployed | 2 | 3 |
| bad | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to duplicate the total frequency in the output? Either way, one of the tables `wordids`, `freqs_df`, or `output` should do be able to help you:

```py
g = df['text'].str.split(expand=True)
g['id'] = df['id']
wordids = g.melt(id_vars=['id']).dropna()[['id', 'value']]
freqs = wordids['value'].value_counts()
freqs_df = pd.DataFrame({'value': freqs.index, 'freq': freqs.values})
output = pd.merge(wordids, freqs_df, on='value')
print(output)
```

Input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 3],
    'text': ['He best work move happy', 'unemployed bad season',
             'best way margin', 'frustated unemployed']
})
```

Output:

```
    id       value  freq
0    1          He     1
1    1  unemployed     2
2    3  unemployed     2
3    2        best     2
4    1        best     2
5    3   frustated     1
6    1         bad     1
7    2         way     1
8    1        work     1
9    1      season     1
10   2      margin     1
11   1        move     1
12   1       happy     1
```